# Rat in a Maze using Stack (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, 2d, maze

We are given a 2D character array and, starting from a given point, we have to find an 'exit', which is a '0' in the perimeter of the given matrix. The program returns true if a path is found, which will print a message when I run it in my main method later. We can only move up, left, down or right to a nearby '0'. I have already tried to make this work, however I get a memory error, which probably means I am stuck in an infinite loop. I have tried to implement this project using a Stack that I made using Nodes, which I also implemented myself using generics, like this: e.g.

```
StringStackImpl<int[][]> s = new StringStackImpl<>();
```

in a different .java file. These work fine. I tried to store the coordinates of a character in the matrix like this:

```
StringStackImpl<int[]> s = new StringStackImpl<>();
s.push(new int[]{i, j});
```

Here is my code:

```
    private static boolean hasExit(char[][] maze, int n, int m, int i, int j) {
    int d = -1;
    boolean[][] visited = new boolean[n][m];
    for (int a = 0; a < visited.length; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < (visited[a]).length; b++) {
            visited[a][b] = false;
        }
    }
    StringStackImpl<int[]> s = new StringStackImpl<>();
    s.push(new int[]{i, j});
    while (!(s.isEmpty())) {
        int[] temp = s.peek();
        d += 1;
        i = temp[0];
        j = temp[1];
        if (((i == 0) || (i == n-1) || (j == 0) || (j == m-1)) && (maze[i][j] == '0')) {
            return true;
        }
        if (d == 0) {
            if ((i-1 >= 0) && (maze[i-1][j] == '0') && !(visited[i-1][j])) {
                visited[i-1][j] = true;
                s.push(new int[]{i-1, j});
                d = -1;
            }
        }
        else if (d == 1) {
            if ((j-1 >= 0) && (maze[i][j-1] == '0') && !(visited[i][j-1])) {
                visited[i][j-1] = true;
                s.push(new int[]{i, j-1});
                d = -1;
            }
        }
        else if (d == 2) {
            if ((i+1 < n) && (maze[i+1][j] == '0') && !(visited[i+1][j])) {
                visited[i+1][j] = true;
                s.push(new int[]{i+1, j});
                d = -1;
            }
        }
        else if (d == 3) {
            if ((j+1 < m) && (maze[i][j+1] == '0') && !(visited[i][j+1])) {
                visited[i][j+1] = true;
                s.push(new int[]{i, j+1});
                d = -1;
            }
        }
        else {
            s.pop();
            d = -1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

EDIT: It works now, thanks to kendavidson! <3

Comment: First off the whole reversal of visited = true (which is actually false) messed me up, if something is visited you do not want to go there, which means you should probably change the initialization of `visited[][] = false;` setting it `true` when you go there.  Popping back to a visited spot is OK but you don't want to reset the spot to unvisited, as if the algorithm is working, you should know that you've exhausted all the routes down that path.  Because you're re-enabling the popped path you're continually going down the same paths.

Comment: So what exactly should I change in my code, except for the whole true-false situation?

Comment: Comment out or remove `visitied[i][j] = true;` from your last `else{ }` clause.  The `d = -1` should be OK in there, as you want to continue the same `s/w/n/e` selection process.

Comment: I 've uploaded the new version, as you said, but, now, it returns false, because it can;t find the path. What is my mistake now?

Comment: Without seeing the maze/starting point it's hard to walk through it.   But at least you should be able to debug it at this point and follow the path without wondering why you're re-tracing steps.

Comment: Actually, you changed the `visited[][] = false` which means you now have to change all your ifs to `&& !visitied[][]` so that they will follow the path.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, and trusting you about StringStackImpl, I think you should only use `d = -1;`in the last `else`. Right now you are always setting it back to -1, and so you only check the `d == 0` condition. From what I understood, `d` is the direction possible, and so should go from `0` to `3` ?

Other than that, take some time to give meaningfull names to your variables :
`visited[i][j]` is true when the node `[i][j]` has not been visited yet... That's counter-intuitive, and doesn't help others, or yourself, from understanding your code.

Are you forced to use `char` for `i` and `j` ? It really tends to make the code long and tedious for nothing.

Comment: Yes, you are right about integer d and about the names, as well. I did not see any way around it, that is why I used char[] for i and j (the same data type as the characters in the maze).

Comment: Using d = -1 only in the last else did not fix the problem. The problem might have to do with temp always being the starting ones in every loop.

Comment: Well, you don't have to peek 4 times the same node. You can peek it once, and do all the logic for the 4 direction, whitout incrementing a  variable.

I'm not 100% sure, but I think everywhere you use `i` and `j` it's in as `int`.
The thing is, `i` and `j` are not `char[]`, they are "iterator" over the array.